# How to switch between two wallpapers (LiveWallpapaer for device & single image as wallpaper for myApp)

Tags: android, wallpaper

One LiveWallpaper is set programatically on device start. Now we need to switch to use an Image as wallpapaer for a single app. Once this app is closed, the liveWallpaper should be back.
OR
Can we make a background image as static so that when activity gets changed, the effect of background image being static looks like wallpaper?

Answer (score 0):

> Before setting the wallpaper programmatically, get the current wallpaper using WallpaperManager.
>
> While leaving app, set the saved wallpaper in onDestroy method.

It will work.